# Как вывести текст в одну строку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день!
Есть блок шириной на весь экран 100%. Через iframe загружаю файл с биржевыми котировками. Однако текст не выводится в одну строку. Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?
И еще один момент: можно ли каким-то образом присвоить свой стиль для выводимого из этого iframe текста?
Благодарю!

```js
$(function() {

   var marquee = $(".stock_quotes_block"); 
   marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});
 
   marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
   marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align":"center" }); 
   marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone());
 
   marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
   marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");
 
   var reset = function() {
    $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
    $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 12000, 'linear', reset);
   };
 
   reset.call(marquee.find("div"));
 
  });
```

```css
.stock_quotes_block {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   height: 25px;
   line-height: 25px;
   margin-top: -25px;
   white-space: nowrap !important;
}
#marquee {
   width: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stock_quotes_block">
    <iframe id="marquee" src="http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=02/03/2002" frameborder="0" height="25" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переиначил задачу: с помощью сервиса yahoo (yahooapis) можно преобразовать данные в json и заодно решить проблему с CORS при запросе (cbr.ru это не поддерживает например). Соответственно из задачи можно убрать iframe и нарисовать по json как будет удобно уже у себя на сайте своими стилями.

```
var getJson = function() {

  $.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbr.ru%2Fscripts%2FXML_daily.asp%3F'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
  .success(function(x){ 
    console.log(x.query.results.ValCurs);
    });

}
getJson();
```

UPD:

```js
var renderList = function(list) {

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
    var divider = '<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';

    var charcode = '<span class="cur-charcode">' + item.CharCode + ' </span>';
    var name = '<span class="cur-name">' + item.Name + ' </span>';
    var value = '<span class="cur-value">' + item.Value + '</span>';
    
    var curblock = '<span class="cur-block">' + charcode + name + value + '</span>' + divider;
    
    $('#mylist').append(curblock);
  }
  
};

var getJson = function() {

  $.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbr.ru%2Fscripts%2FXML_daily.asp%3F'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
  .success(function(x){ 
    renderList(x.query.results.ValCurs.Valute);
  });

};

getJson();
```

```css
.garage-title {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cur-block .cur-charcode {
  color: #595;
}

.cur-block .cur-name {
  color: #599;
}

.cur-block .cur-value {
  color: #559;
}

.cur-block .cur-value {
  /* padding-right: 4px; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<marquee behavior="scroll" weight="150" loop="infinity" truespeed="5" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
  <div id='mylist' class='garage-title'></div>
</marquee>
```

Comment: добавил работающий код в ответ. и да, javascript код должен быть либо в <script> либо подгружен как js файл.

Comment: `var acceptedCurrencies = ['USD', 'EUR'];
...
var item = list[i];

if ($.inArray(item.CharCode, acceptedCurrencies) >= 0) {
  ...
  $('#mylist').append(curblock);
}`

Comment: Вот тот же пример в фиддле но уже с фильтрацией: https://jsfiddle.net/y8avgpk7/3/
попробуйте то, что у вас не работает также оформить в код, который можно расшарить ссылкой, jsfiddle, codepen и т.д.

Comment: вот проапдейтил тот же пример в jsfiddle, например так: https://jsfiddle.net/y8avgpk7/4/
мысль в том что сначала мы фильтруем, а для отображения идем по тому массиву, порядок которого нам важен.
Но вообще тянет на отдельный вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

Много лишних стилей. Тут не запустится - на [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KybGzj) работает, проверяйте.

```js
$(function() {

  var marquee = $(".stock_quotes_block"); 
  marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});
 
  marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
  marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align":"center" }); 
  marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone());
 
  marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
  marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");
 
  var reset = function() {
    $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
    $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 12000, 'linear', reset);
  };
 
  reset.call(marquee.find("div"));
 
});
```

```css
.stock_quotes_block {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#marquee {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stock_quotes_block">
  <iframe id="marquee" src="http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=02/03/2002" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @LADYX У меня [в одну строку](http://dropmefiles.com/oFQhS) отображает, без переходов.